# How do I load Javascript library to make it available to the Javascript on a page in a WebBrowser Control in Windows Phone?

Tags: javascript, windows-phone, browser

I need to build support for MRAID compliant ads that will be shown in a WebBrowser control on Windows Phone 8 devices.  MRAID defines a set of 23 methods and 5 events that are to be available for the ad designer to use from their JavaScript.  So, I need to build a library of those 23 JavaScript methods and 5 JavaScript events.  Each of them will use windows.external.Notify to call a C# function that will supply the actual method and return the requested data to the JavaScript function using webBrowser.InvokeScript.

So the question that has me stumped is how do I load the JavaScript library that I build so those functions are available to the Ad designer?

My only idea is to dynamically parse the Ad's HTML and inject my JavaScript into the Ad before pointing the WebBrowser control at it but this seems very clumsy and error prone.

Your ideas and suggestions would be appreciated.